# Can not install visual studio ultimate 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Getting this error after system restore point created

[image]

I have vc runtime x64 already installed, rebooted several times. No idea what pre-clean tool and msvs preparation is

Any ideas? Fresh win 7 x64 sp1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have vc runtime x64 already installed, rebooted several times.

The `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Runtime` is not binary compatible.  This mean if an application required 11.0.61030 you had to install that specific version. If another application wanted, a different version, you had to also install that version. **The `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime` only became binary compatible with previous versions recently (VC++ 2017+).**

> No idea what the `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pre-Clean Tool` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation` is exactly

They are scripts used by the installer.  This problem is due to your ISO being corrupt.

> Any ideas?

Download another copy of the Visual Studio 2012 ISO.  The installation process for Visual Studio 2019 is several hundred times better, **anything you wanted to do within Visual Studio 2012**, can be done within Visual Studio 2019.  You really should be installing a version of Visual Studio that is actually supported.

Source:

- [VS2012 Error on setup on Windows 8 - Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146692/vs2012-error-on-setup-on-windows-8-visual-c-2012-x86-minimum-runtime-cannot)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional Setup Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739335/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-pro-setup-failed)